# Docker MongoDB container endlessly restarts on macOS

Tags: docker, macos

The MongoDB docker container infinitely restarts every few seconds on local docker env, even though it used to work.

Env: macOS 13.2.1, docker 4.17.0, Engine: 20.10.23, Compose: 1.29.2, Credential Helper: v0.7.0

I tried to delete the MongoDB database folder and fetch the image again, but the MongoDB log contains only these:

```
> 09:10:08.38 Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
> 09:10:08.40 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb
> 09:10:08.42 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/issues
> 09:10:08.43 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
> 09:10:08.45  
> 09:10:08.46 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB setup **
> 09:10:08.53 INFO ==> Validating settings in MONGODB_* env vars...
> 09:10:08.56 INFO  ==> Initializing MongoDB...
> 09:10:08.63 INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB from scratch...
> 09:10:08.67 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf detected!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution:

1. Uncheck the "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" option under Settings > Features in development
2. Restart Docker

The AMD64-based containers function but run very slowly now, and I'm almost sure the same container used to work with the same option checked.